# Display the contents of an UDP package via Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, plotly-dash

I would like to dynamically update an html div when an udp packet is received at port xxxx. Anyone know how to merge these two parts?

By merging the code I am unable to execute both, for example saving in a variable the value received from the udp packet.

Html code:

**DASH**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

ERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Value:"),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Udp socket:

**UDP**

```
HEADER = 64
PORT = 4501
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    connected = True
    while connected:
            msg = conn.recv(1024)
            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a few things to get started:

- Asynchronous background task manager (i.e. Celery, check out [Celery Tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#basics)).
- Use a database to store and pass contents of the socket (Celery utilizes Redis or RabbitMQ, for example).
- In a dcc.Interval object, query the database to get the latest value and display that value in your Dash app.

Comment: The purpose of my project is only to visualize in real time the data sent by a sensor in udp.
So I don't need to save in the database. How can I move in this direction?